# Not able to resize a small image to larger image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image-resizing

In my program user can upload an image  upto specific size and after that i am resizing an image. It works great if image is big , but if image is small and I try to resize to big image get blurred (basically its just zooming instead of resizing)...Can someone help how can I do that.Thanks!!

Here is my program

```
 public static Image ScaleBySize(Image imgPhoto, int size)
        {
            int logoSize = size;

            float sourceWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
            float sourceHeight = imgPhoto.Height;
            float destHeight = 0;
            float destWidth = 0;
            int sourceX = 0;
            int sourceY = 0;
            int destX = 0;
            int destY = 0;




            if (sourceWidth > size || sourceWidth < size) { destWidth = size; }
            if (sourceHeight > size || sourceHeight < size) { destHeight = size; }


            Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap((int)destWidth, (int)destHeight,PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
            bmPhoto.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution, imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);

            Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
            grPhoto.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPhoto,new Rectangle(destX, destY, (int)destWidth, (int)destHeight),new Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, (int)sourceWidth, (int)sourceHeight),GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            grPhoto.Dispose();

            return bmPhoto;
        }
```

Comment: Your best bet would be to leave an image smaller than your required size the same size.  Only resize downward to eliminate distortion

Answer (score 2):

Of course you large image will be blurred since there is no detail in the small image. The program is only "stretching" each pixel to fill a larger area.

Comment: Is there any way to do it...??

Comment: @user207888 - no, there isn't.  There is only so much information in an image of a given size.  Taking a 50px x 50px image and trying to make it fill 200px x 200px will cause it to distort as each pixel is now essentially made into 16 pixels - major distortion. Only in CSI can you blow up a grainy image and have it as clear as the original :)

Comment: Oh K, may be i then just center the small image and resize the big images..Thanks!!

Comment: This is why the "Zoom! Enhance image!" silliness in movies is so jarring. Just can't be done reasonably well (nothing from nothing leaves nothing).